# spring data for mongodb with map based find

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Spring data offers various repositories for CRUD, paging and sorting for mongodb.
When we need a document from mongodb using various attributes, we tend to write the `findBy` method or write a method with explicit query annotated with **`@Query`**.
But if my document has many properties and I need various means of fetching the document, does spring offer a "repository method" which takes in a Map of attributes and values?
Writing various `findBy` may be cumbersome. Using [QueryDSL](http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) seems to be an option but requires code generation and build.gradle changes. I can use QueryDSL if map based solution is not available.

For ex:

```java
class FooDocument {
    String id ;//mongodb ObjectId
    String name
    String version
    boolean deleteIndicator
    ... any more attributes
}
```

Need a method on the repository like

```java
 List<FooDocument> findByMap ( Map attrValMap );
```

Call the method (groovy)

```java
repository.findByMap ( [ "name" : "fooname", "version" : "1.0" ] )
repository.findByMap ( [ "name" : "fooname"] )
repository.findByMap ( [ "version" : "1.0", "deleteIndicator" : false] )
```

Am willing to write this method using `Criteria/Query` combination or `BasicDBObject` based fetch using MongoOperations interface in case spring data does not offer this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Spring Data can do it easily. But if you are willing to use MongoDB's `BasicDBObject` to get what you need, then you can use it in the following way:

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", "fooname").append("version", "1.0");
DBCursor cursor = find(doc);
List<FooDocument> fooDocList = new ArrayList<FooDocument>();
while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
    DBObject obj = cursor.next(); 
    FooDocument foo = mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(FooDocument.class, obj);  
    fooDocList.add(foo); 
}
```

Comment: Query option seems to be easier. I can declare findByQuery(Query query) method on the repository and provide a custom implementation of this method which delegates the call to MongoOperations#methods which accept Query instance. I need not mess with iterating and fetching. But was hoping spring repository to provide such functionality out-of-the-box for mongodb.